# Firefox Add-on enable CORS domain request

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox Add-on, i'm failing to send request from popup script. it is showing some error

> Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

In chrome extension working fine.

Popup script

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/user/66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799/emailtemplate/c60d870eaad6a3946ab3e8734466e532',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'accessToken': 'Krc7YPoZPaYiy37O', 'appID': '28fdd9c013e37bca7dd875b10817b694', 'appSecret': '15798907115476fdf1de7a8' },
    success: function(eventSettingsResponse) {
        buildTemplate(eventDetailsResponse, eventSettingsResponse);
        console.log('This is content script testing...', eventDetailsResponse);
    },
    error: function() {  }
    //beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Package.json

```
{
 "title": "First",
 "name": "test",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "description": "Just for testing",
 "main": "index.js",
 "author": "Bharath",
 "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
 },
 "permissions": {
 "cross-domain-content": ["http://localhost/*"]
},
"license": "MIT"
}
```

Main.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
include: ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
contentScriptFile: data.url("js/content.js"),
contentScriptWhen: 'end',
onAttach: function(worker) {
worker.port.emit("init", urls);
worker.port.on("showPopup", function() {
    console.log('port received');
    windows.open(data.url('popup/popup.html'), {
        name: 'jetpack window',
        features: {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            popup: false
        }
    });
});
    worker.port.on("returnHtml", function() {
        console.log('Html returnde.');
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts#Cross-domain_XMLHttpRequest) that I could add the following to package.json

```
  "permissions": {
      "cross-domain-content": ["https://data.com"]
  }
```